# Is there way to use rename-item on a files that do not have an extension?

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

I am trying to rename a file and then copy a file to that location, the error I am getting is that

> Rename-Item : Cannot rename because item at .... does not exist.

The issue I believe is that the file does not have an extension, so I have something like:

```
rename-item "\\$serverName\c$\temp\filename" -NewName filename.$currentdate
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I doubt it is because of no extension. `Rename-Item` works fine with such files or folders.

In your example, you are missing one \ at the beginning, there should be two of them.

Anyway if you want to be sure, you may use following *(you should have variable $currentdate already populated)*:

```
$name = '\\$serverName\c$\temp\filename'
Get-Item $name | Rename-Item -NewName "filename.$currentdate"
```

With those two commands you will see if it fails on Get-Item or on Rename-Item.

Comment: Thanks Igor ,  Weirdly it worked piping the path into Rename-Item not sure why it fails without the pipe.  Anyways you are timesaver!